# Display Scope Variable in AngularJS Template

Tags: angularjs, templates, variables, scope

I'm running into a very odd situation trying to display a simple scope variable inside an angularjs template.  Here's the simplified template code:

```
<div id="Parent" data-ng-controller="MyController">
    {{ScopeVariable}} <!-- Diplays Just Fine -->

    <div>
          ... Some Buttons ...
          {{ScopeVariable}} <!-- Here it displays as {{ScopeVariable}}.  Why? -->
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="SomeElement in SomeScopeArray">
          {{ScopeVariable}}  <!-- Diplays Just Fine -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The same single scope variable displays correctly inside the controller element as well as a repeated div.  But if I try to display it inside a simple div, it fails.

Comment: Can you put together a Plunker demoing the problem.

Comment: the problem is most likely in the ... Some Buttons ... section. Check your closing tags because chances are {{ScopeVariable}} is being read as an attribute of a button that is lacking a closing tag.

Comment: Don't you have more curly braces inside 'Some Buttons' div?
Try <span ng-bind="ScopeVariable"></span> instead of {{}}.